# Is it safe to save experience and gold attributes (RPG-like) in a .plist-file?

Tags: ios, iphone, database, cocos2d-iphone, save

I want to store earned xp and gold, so that my game loads the data whenever the game starts. I am using cocos2d on the iPhone, what would be a safe (doesn't need to be toooo safe) to store such data?

I don't want the user to be able to modify the xp-points too easily. Is that possible with .plists? Or do I have to use a Database like  SQL lite? It would be very nice if the user couldn't just change the values of the .plist that easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about storing the information in a dictionary, archiving it, then encrypting the data with one of the many available encryption categories like the one shared by [Aquatic](http://aquaticmac.com/cocoa.php)?

Nothing you can do would stop a determined and experienced hacker but this would make it difficult / *effectively* impossible for the average user.

Comment: Hi, I checked your link but in the developer guide there are just tutorials for creating/checking licensces. I have never used encryption before, is there another good source/program where I can get some more infos and that is easy to use? If I dont's use any encryption, say I just use plain .plists, will they be unreadable to people who doesn't have a jailbroken device?

Comment: Check it again. The page I linked you to is a self-contained category on NSData with the two methods (encrypt/decrypt) that take an NSString password. That's it.

Comment: As to the plist file, yes, those who don't have a jailbroken device won't be able to mess with the application data unless you build in document sharing, etc. and expose it on purpose. Using the binary plist format (versus XML) makes it even harder to read/edit without the Property List Editor app that comes with Xcode Tools.

Answer (score 2):

It may be easiest to use NSUserPreferences.

Comment: Is it save to do it that way? I don't want the user to loose all his gold and xp because of a bug that may occur. Or is the app data saved via synchronizing with Itunes? There's some more values I want to save, such as ID's for different items (maybe 40 items) etc. Isn't that too much for the NSUserPreferences?