# Where should I save gold/exp attributes of my cocos2d Iphone Game?

Tags: iphone, database, cocos2d-iphone, plist, nsuserdefaults

I'd like to save my gold and experience attributes so that they can be retrieved whenever the app launches.

I don't know whether I should use .plists or NSUserdefaults. What's the difference? Can I somewhere manually edit the NSUserdefaults outside of the code like I can do it with plists? The problem is, I don't want the user to loose all his gold/exp for any reason.

Gold and exp are both integer values. Do you think NSUserdefaults would be the right choice?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it safe to save experience and gold attributes (RPG-like) in a .plist-file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174316/is-it-safe-to-save-experience-and-gold-attributes-rpg-like-in-a-plist-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSUserDefaults are retained during an upgrade. It is easy to use to (a one-liner to save/restore settings).

They are not available to anyone who could tamper with them - unless they jailbroke the phone, then I suppose people could get at them no matter what method you use.

If you are totally paranoid about that scenario, you could encrypt/decrypt the data during save/restore, but that's probably overkill.